# Fetch relational object from cache

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

I have below code that fetches users and relational role object for each user.

```
$query = (new UserModel())->newQuery();
$query->with("Role");
$data = $query->get(["UserName", "EmailAddress", "User_ID"]);
```

I have 3 roles present in database and they are in cache.
Is there any way to change this line of code: `$query->with("Role");` such that while fetching the users each time, it will not need to fetch roles from database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can hook into the Retrieved event from Eloquent. When retrieving the model from the Database you can fetch the role from the cache and set it on the model. Perhaps that could be a solution for you?

Take a look at the Laravel Docs on eloquent events here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events

Maybe this will work out something for you, add this to your model class:

```
/**
 * Boot the model.
 */
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::retrieving(function ($user) {
        $user->fetchFromCache("Role"); //replace this line with however you could fetch it from the cache
    });
}
```

Comment: I did, not that hard. But you have to write the logic to fetch it from the cache yourself. Keep in mind you should always have a backup. Like if it does not exist in cache you should fetch it from the DB and cache it.